# What is the consideration when installing or replacing the shaft of an induction motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction-motor, electromagnetic, magnetic-flux

[image: Front axis' view]

[image: Rear axis' view]

Here are two picture of my washing machine's motor. I am not sure whether you still have such that machine in your country. It is a top loading washing machine's washing motor (a another smaller one is called a spinning motor). It is a 4-poles induction motor. I would like to modify (or to retrofit?) it to suit to my need by open the cover and change the shaft so I can install pulley on both side of the motor, in 'front' and in the 'rear' side. And I will also replace its native bearing to a 6000 ball bearing as it is more common and stronger, so does the winding I will change the coil to a better one a pure copper rather than using aluminum as it is now. A fan also I will install on one side cool it down when it is working.

But here my focus is about the shaft. What I want to ask is, *what is the **electro-magnetic consideration** when replacing that shaft*? As we knew, the core stacks are laminated so they don't have contact between one and another with intention to reduce eddy's current swirling in the core. But I never found explanation about the interaction of the core and the shaft which it is the core that hold the shaft. The shaft is sitting on the core. When I take out the existing shaft and re-install the more suitable one, *what do I need to consider*? *Can be the laminated core have contact with the shaft*? Or, *what will happen if they have contact*?

**Note:**
Even this is sound very mechanical but as this is about induction, about magnetic, I believe this is part of electrical too rather than mechanical.

Comment: the term is `axle` ... axis is an imaginary centerline

Comment: @jsotola, alright. I will use shaft rather than axle as I just checked Google Translate, the more proper word is probably ***axles*** (with **s**) rather than just ***axle***. So, shaft is probably the most suitable and will not confusing.

Comment: Shaft is the normal term in English. By the time you've made all your proposed changes there won't be much left of the original motor, which wasn't designed for easy modification. You may find it easier to find a dual shaft motor or rework your mechanical design to use your existing single shaft motor.

Comment: @GrahamNye, unfortunately I could not find a suitable one. Yes actually will be just left the laminated core stack, nothing more left.

Comment: Whilst it is a valid question and I don’t have the expertise to give a valid answer but nevertheless the configuration you describe is not unusual. You can simply test if there is contact between the existing shaft and the rotor. If there is, then extending the shaft will make little difference methinks.  This is a one-off, so ‘suck it and see’. If it works - bonus.if it doesn’t then hopefully you’ve learned something.